# Is there any good example of gitignore file for Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, gitignore

Is there any good example or way how to create `.gitignore` file for `Zend Framework 2`?

Comment: The GitHub gitignore repository has a ZendFramework .gitignore: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/ZendFramework.gitignore

Comment: Yep but this is Zend 1 and I'm looking for Zend 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the one from the ZendSkeletonApplication. https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/.gitignore.